# How can I include a list of what a user ordered (the line items) in an e-mail sent by Drupal Commerce?

Tags: commerce, rules, emails

I want to send an e-mail that contains the content of a user's Drupal Commerce order (the line items) with Rules.

I tried modifying the default **Send an order notification e-mail** (in Rules) provided by Commerce.  I noticed that there was a `[commerce-order:commerce_line_items]` token, but when I insert this into an e-mail, I get a message of *No line items found* when the e-mail is sent, even though the order has line items.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[commerce-order:commerce_line_items]` token does not work when *Completing the checkout process*, which is the event for which the **Send an order notification e-mail** rule is triggered.

Instead, one way to do this is to use the [Commerce E-mail](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_email) module, which provides a `[commerce-order:commerce-email-order-items]` token and a new interface for editing the e-mail.  Note that you will need to disable the e-mail-sending rule when using this module (or else you will get duplicate e-mails, as the module help points out).

Comment: You can change the output of [commerce-order:commerce_line_items] so that it includes all line items (such as shipping, tax). See [link](http://websitebackendsolutions.com/blog/how-display-all-drupal-commerce-line-items-using-token)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Message](http://www.drupal.org/project/message) module together with [Commerce Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_message) and [Message Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_notify), another way of doing this would be to simply use the token `!order-summary` in the `commerce_order_order_confirmation` message type provided by the module Commerce Message.

All you have to do is edit the message type at the following URL and add the token in the corresponding field:

```
admin/structure/messages/manage/commerce_order_order_confirmation
```

The rule `Commerce order message: order notification e-mail` will then send an e-mail after checkout is completed which will include the line items.

Comment: Hi @Bmunslow. Any idea why the Commerce order message: order notification e-mail rule could be missing in a commerce site w. commerce message installed? Can you export the rule?

Comment: @KristofferRom I have no idea why that rule would be missing from your setup.  Make sure it hasn't been disabled.
I once had an issues with rules disappearing as well, it was due to a complex i18n setup...
I can't paste the full rule in this comments...
You can copy / paste from here: [http://pastebin.com/rvvpywX8](http://pastebin.com/rvvpywX8)